# C# - Serial Port Distinction Between 32-bit WinXP and 64-bit Win10?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, windows-10, windows-xp

I have a question concerning sending/receiving data over a serial port on a Visual Studio application. My serial port, for certain reasons, was initialized to the following:

```
        SerialPort.BaudRate = 230400;
        SerialPort.DataBits = 8;
        SerialPort.DiscardNull = false;
        SerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
        SerialPort.Parity = Parity.Mark;
        SerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.Two;
        SerialPort.DtrEnable = true;
        SerialPort.RtsEnable = true;
```

This works with a Prolific Serial-to-USB device on my Windows 10 (64 bit) machine under an x86 build and .NET version 4.0. However, once this is ported over to my Windows XP machine (32 bit) under the same settings, it sends a bunch of junk instead. The application still launches and the byte array that is to be sent is correct, it's just that sending it goes wrong. Specifically, a 0-0-0 byte array pattern gets sent as 96-12-3 (or some permutation thereof). Does anyone have any ideas as to why this might be?

Thank you guys so much in advance!

Comment: Windows XP is end of life, so this question should be considered "not reproducible". Nobody should use that any more.

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out? If not, are you sure the Baud Rate of 230400 is supported by the serial port on your XP machine? The docs state "The baud rate must be supported by the user's serial driver."